# How to simplify $2 q^{\frac{k-1}{2}} n^2 - \sigma(q^{\frac{k-1}{2}})\sigma(n^2)$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-verification, modular-arithmetic, divisor-sum, arithmetic-functions

Let $k$ be a positive integer satisfying $k \equiv 1 \pmod 4$.  Let $x \in \mathbb{N}$.  Let $q$ be a prime number.

If 
$$\sigma(x) = \sum_{d \mid x}{d}$$
is the classical sum-of-divisors function, then how do I simplify the following expression?

> $$2 q^{\frac{k-1}{2}} n^2 - \sigma(q^{\frac{k-1}{2}})\sigma(n^2)$$

When $k=1$, this is just
$$2n^2 - \sigma(n^2) = D(n^2)$$
where $D(x)=2x-\sigma(x)$ is the [deficiency](http://oeis.org/A033879) of $x$.

How about when $k>1$?  Does the expression have a nice form?

**MY ATTEMPT**

Since $k>1$ and $k \equiv 1 \pmod 4$, then $k \geq 5$, which implies that
$$\sigma(q^{\frac{k-1}{2}}) = q^{\frac{k-1}{2}} + \ldots + q + 1 = q^{\frac{k-1}{2}} + \sigma(q^{\frac{k-3}{2}})$$
so that we obtain
$$2 q^{\frac{k-1}{2}} n^2 - \sigma(q^{\frac{k-1}{2}})\sigma(n^2) = 2 q^{\frac{k-1}{2}} n^2 - q^{\frac{k-1}{2}} \sigma(n^2) - \sigma(q^{\frac{k-3}{2}}) \sigma(n^2)$$
$$= q^{\frac{k-1}{2}} D(n^2) - \sigma(q^{\frac{k-3}{2}}) \sigma(n^2)$$

> > Is my derivation correct?

Note that when $\gcd(q,n)=1$, then this is just
$$2 q^{\frac{k-1}{2}} n^2 - \sigma(q^{\frac{k-1}{2}})\sigma(n^2) = 2 q^{\frac{k-1}{2}} n^2 - \sigma\left(q^{\frac{k-1}{2}} n^2\right) = D\bigg(q^{\frac{k-1}{2}} n^2\bigg).$$

Comment: Your derivation is correct.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback, @Cardioid_Ass_22.